# How to check Internet connection on a Cordova App?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, networking, connection

I tried some suggestions, such as **navigator.onLine**, but even in flight mode, my app "thinks" its online.

I found some suggestions with ajax too, but I just want to check if I'm online to open an external web page. If not, I intend to show a message such as "Your device seems to be offline. Check your connection!".

Comment: and what seems to be the problem? can't you do if you get an error when trying to connect to service show that message?

Answer (score 17):

The best approach is to use `cordova network information plugin` which does the job for you seamlessly. This plugin provides information about the device's cellular and wifi connection, and whether the device has an internet connection.

You check out the [official github page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) of this plugin for more info on the same. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

Download the plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-network-information

And Try This.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(e){
        console.log(navigator.connection.type);
        document.addEventListener("offline", function(e){
                            alert("NO_NETWORK");

        }, false);  
}, false);
```

**offline**

The event fires when an application goes offline, and the device is not connected to the Internet.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Answer (score 7):

you can  use this [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information#readme)

then you can use it everywhere in your App without to import it

```
if(navigator.connection.type === 'none') {
   alert('there is no internet')
 }
```

and you can add it into setInterval to check for internet connection every 5 seconds

```
  setInterval(() => {
        if(navigator.connection.type === 'none') {
            alert('there is no internet')
        } }, 5000);
```

there are another values for "avigator.connection.type"
for example when there is internet then the value of "avigator.connection.type" is the type of connection (wifi, 4g, 3g, ethernet on windows .... )

Answer (score 4):

By [this](http://cordova%20plugin%20add%20cordova-plugin-network-information)

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

Comment: when the device connected via WIFI, this function will give us a true even if there is no internet connection in the hotspot

Answer (score 0):

you can check the connectivity of your android device to internet by using `cordova-plugin-network-information` plugin. furthermore if you want to perform certain task on the availability of the internet, see below:

```
if (navigator.connection.type == "none") {
    alert("No Internet Connection...");
    
}
else {
    yourdesiredFunction();
}
```